# pass an variable as an argument for an setInterval function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass an variable to `setInterval` in angularjs and returned after the interval to another function

Example:

```
$scope.start = function(host_id) {
  // store the interval promise
    $scope[`promise_${host_id}`] = $interval(function(host_id){
        $scope.update_status(host_id)
    }, 3000);
};

// stops the interval
$scope.stop = function(host_id) {
    $interval.cancel($scope[`promise_${host_id}`]);
};
```

`$scope.start(5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) as reference [example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/hGwhsyEhi0veu55S)

```
$interval(updateTime, 1000, 0,true,'my arguments')// can be array as well
```